# Wordpress search showing shortcode for visual composer used

Tags: wordpress, function, search

i have used Mymoun theme for wordpress website. the theme having visual composer which is good and easy to use.. Now after finishing website i have issue with search result as pages showing short code before the content for example

[vc_row][vc_column][vc_single_image image="2801" img_size="full"][/vc_column][vc_column][wd_headings headings_title="Health, Safety and Environment" headings_title_tag="h1" headings_subtitle="" headings_alignment="left" wd_heading_font_weight="400" wd_sub_heading_font_weight="400" wd_heading_spacing="15"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]Ep's employees are its strength and Ep does all that it can to provide a safe and healthy environment to its people and community at large. As a responsible corporate citizen, Ep has committed itself to conduct its manufacturing process in such a manner, which will do no harm to its personnel and environment. EnerPlastics LLC has..

Any one have any idea, how to hide these shortcode from search

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be solved by go to dashboard => Plugins => and activate Visual Composer plugin.
or that shortcode is out date and not compatible with the Visual Composer version you are using.
You can open search.php file and remove this shortcode on this file.

Comment: Hi, cant find code in search.php file and the plugin came with theme. should i repurchase to activate..

Comment: Hi, You try to copy that shortcode to another page content then check this page in the default theme. To make sure that shortcode is not out date. If the problem don't occur with default theme, that mean your theme has a problem with VC.